# Is it posible to get the value from an asp.net Label, that was set by javascript in the code-behind?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

im setting the Label value, with JavaScript, and the with a button click i want to acces it in the code behind.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use a hidden field to hold the value, because label text is not submitted into the server as form data.

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server">
<asp:Button ID="BtnClick" runat="server" onClientClick="SetName();"/>
<asp:Button ID="btnShow" runat="server" onClick="btnShow_Click"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
   function SetName()
     {
       document.getElementById("<%=lblName.ClientID%>").InnerHTML ='Hello';
     }

</script>

 From Coding:
 protected void btnShow_Click(object sender,EventArgs e)
   {
      string name = lblName.Text;
   }
```